# How do I proceed with a question like this?

Tags: c++, logic

Good Evening everyone. I am not really sure as to whether it is against the rules to ask questions like these on this platform (If it is, kindly tell me). The question is  of a "practice competition". I could complete 5 of 10 test cases but I am not sure what is wrong in this. Please suggest any correction/logic/hint... And Time Complexity must be less than O(n^2) (According to the input given)

[image]

The approach I tried is:

```cpp
int main() {
  /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
  signed long int t, n;
  scanf("%d", &t);
  for (int i = 1; i <= t; i++) {
    int count = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n <= 10)
      count = n;
    else {
      // count = 9;
      string s;
      s = to_string(n);
      int len = s.length();
      int x = n / (pow(10, len - 2));
      int h = x / 11;
      string y = to_string(x);
      if (y.length() <= 2)
        x = 0;
      count = (9 * (len - 1)) + x + h;
    }
    printf("%d\n", count);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Please suggest whatever you feel is helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: Your title isn't descriptive. Please write a title that summarizes the specific problem. Have a look here: [ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, it sounds like you are trying to get us to do the work for you. [Understand the difference between "asking a question about your homework" and "asking a specific question about the code in your homework"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Using `std::string` can be avoided for your computation: `to_string(n).length()` might be replaced by `floor(log10(n) + 1)` . `to_string(x).length() <= 2` -> `x < 100`

Comment: Has it actually occured to you that printing all nine so-called "beautiful numbers" that are, for example, three digits long, specifically 111 through 999, can be done without actually individually testing each number from 100 to 999 to see if it is a so-called "beautiful number"? If you take a moment to ponder this fact, and wrap your brain around it, a much simpler solution should occur to you, and you should realize that all the code shown above is a completely wrong approach.

Comment: Also what's the reason you post the actual question as image instead of copy-pasting it as text? Images make the question less accessbile, and harder to read.

Comment: @churill PrtScr ;)

Comment: *"Complexity must be less than O(n^2)"* what is `n` here? input number? number of digits of input number? Notice that brute force would lead to `O(n)` (with n input number)...

Comment: @Jarod42 n is input number. And by brute force ( I think it means checking one by one), it would give a time complexity of O(n^2). In my view, it would go like this: One loop generates a number to be checked which is less than "n" (int i = 1; i <= n; i++).... One loop is required to check whether it is palindrome or not.(Either by converting it into string and then comparing it with reversed string or extracting digits and checking whether all the digits are same or not).

Comment: @SubMachine Hello sir, yes I agree that the title isn't descriptive. I will take care of that in the future questions which I would be asking. I am not asking you to do my work. The thing is, I devoted time into it, around 3 to 4 hours, trying everything I could. At that moment, I felt I needed help, thus I contacted this website. I hope this is allowed here.

Comment: @churill Hello sir, I thought posting an image was much more convenient as compared to posting the text. I will take that into consideration from now on.

Comment: Brute force would be: `int count = 0; for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i) { if (is_beautiful(i)) ++count; }` -> `O(n)`. complexity of `is_beautiful` would be O(nb_digits). (resulting to `O(n log10 n)`).

Comment: @BeardedOwl, if you devoted time into it, you should have described what exactly you already tried and where you are stuck, this is part of asking a good question on StackOverflow. We can't guess it.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complex problem.
Assuming your input is correct so we don’t have to do any checking we observe:

1. If number n is single digit the number of beautiful numbers is b = n.
2. If number n is double digit and the first digit is f, then the number of beautiful numbers b = 9 + x, where x is a number of all beautiful double digit numbers smaller than n,
3. If number n is triple digit and the first digit is f, then the number of beautiful numbers b = 2 x 9 + x, where x is a number of all beautiful triple digit numbers smaller than n.
4. And so on and on

Thus we can extrapolate: If number n has d digits, than the number of beautiful numbers

s = (d-1) * 9 + x,

where x is a number of beautiful d-digit numbers smaller than or equal to n.
So your problem was reduced to finding x. And this can be reduced even further. Take for instance number n = 44437. The important number here is first digit f. It is trivial to see that all 5 digit beautiful numbers that begin where single digits are less then f are ok. In our example 11111, 22222, 33333 are ok, while 444444 and larger are not.

So all you need to do is to check if beautiful number fffff is smaller than or equal to n. And this can be done with simple traversal of input string.
So your solution would be:

s = (d-1) * 9 + (f-1) + supersecretsauce,

where:

s - solution

n – your input number of age

d – number of digits, assuming your input is always correct is length(n)

f – first digit of your number n

supersecretsauce – 1 if fff…f is smaller or equal than n, 0 if bigger.
And even the traversal of input string can be optimized, but I leave that to you.

Oh yeah... and the time complexity of this solution O(n) = length(n) = log10(n).

Comment: Why is the complexity `O(n)`?  If that is what you calculated, there are even faster ways of doing this, totally different than your approach.  For example, pre-generate the entire table of beautiful numbers in sorted order, and then simply do a binary search on this table.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The complexity is actually length(n) because all you actually have to do is traverse an input string of number n. Alternatively if you are working in number domain you would have to construct a beautiful number of length d and compare it with n, which also boils down to O(d). Your proposal might be promising, Of course you will trade time requirements for space requirements, but since beautiful numbers are sparse it might work. And for every beautiful number you would also have to precompile the number of smaller beautiful numbers.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Pardon my mistake. I have made a type regarding O(n). I have edited my answer. The complexity is actually O(n) = length(n), depends on number of digits.

Comment: Sure, there is a tradeoff in space using a table.  I will post an answer.

Comment: @user6694745 Good evening. I understood majority of your logic ( I feel we arrived at the same conclusion but you did it brilliantly). But I have a question: What is the logic behind "supersecretsauce"? I think it was meant for single digit number, let me explain. If n = 8, f = 8. d = 1. Therefore, count = 0 + 8 - 1 + supersecretsauce. In this case, since (f <= n) {Like you said}, it is 1 and therefore count  = f. But I don't understand, how can f be greater than n? Lets say the number 100500. f = 1, always <= n. According to logic, answer = 46. But it is 45...

Comment: I doubt we came to the same conclusion. If we had it would be clear to you. The formula using d and f gives you the number of all the beautiful numbers which have less digits than n plus the number of beautiful numbers which have the same number of digits as n and are trivially smaller than n. So the only thing you have to check if a d-digit beautiful number (let’s call this number b) consisting only of digits f is less or equal to n. And this is your secret sauce. We add 1 if this number is equal or smaller to n.

Comment: @BeardedOwl Let me go through your examples. For n=8 -> f = 8, d = 1, b=1 and therefore sss=1. Solution s = (d-1)*9 + (f-1) + 1 = 0*9 + 7 +1 = 8. Next example n=100500 -> f=1, d=6, b = 111111 and therefore ssc = 0. And the solution is: (6-1)*9 + (1-1) + 0 = 45. BTW: Is this a proficiency recruiting question?

Comment: @user6694745 Really thank you sir. I finally understood it. And this was just an event conducted by one of my college clubs.

Answer (score 2):

For the problem, given that the work area you are dealing with is relatively small (the number of beautiful numbers less than 10^9 can be reasonably handled with a table of those values), here is a version of a solution that uses a pre-generated table of all of the beautiful numbers in sorted order.

Once the table is set up, it is just a matter of doing a binary search to determine the number of beautiful numbers there are that occur before the input value.  The position of the closest beautiful number in the table is the number of beautiful numbers we need.

The binary search is done by utilizing the `<algorithm>` function [std::upper_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound).  This function will return an iterator to the item that is greater than the search item.  Then to get the position, `std::distance` is used (we subtract 1, since `std::upper_bound` will give us the item that is greater than the searched item).

The generation of the table can be done at compile-time (by hand, just initializing an array), or if you're lazy, generated at runtime with a simple loop.  Here is one such solution:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<int> values;

int generate_value(int digit, int numTimes)
{
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numTimes; ++i)
        total = 10 * total + digit;
    return total;
}

// I'm lazy, so let the program generate the table for me
void generate_values()
{
    size_t curIdx = 0;
    values.push_back(0);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 9; ++j)
            values.push_back(generate_value(j, i));
    }
    values.push_back(1111111111);
}

// does a binary search and returns the position of the beautiful number
int beautiful(int num)
{
    if (num == 0)
        return 1;

    // get iterator to closest number equaling the beautiful number
    auto iter = std::upper_bound(values.begin(), values.end(), num);

    // get distance from beginning of vector
    return std::distance(values.begin(), iter) - 1;
}

int main()
{
    generate_values();
    std::cout << beautiful(18) << "\n";;
    std::cout << beautiful(1) << "\n";;
    std::cout << beautiful(9) << "\n";;
    std::cout << beautiful(100500) << "\n";;
    std::cout << beautiful(33) << "\n";;
    std::cout << beautiful(1000000000) << "\n";;
}
```

Output:

```
10
1
9
45
12
81
```

The size of the table is in total, 83 entries, thus a binary search of this table will take no more than `log(83)` checks to find the value, which is at most 7 probes in the table.

Comment: Upvote for the effort. All those push_back cause a lot of new allocations.

Comment: The push_backs are not anything to focus on -- I only done it that way because that's the way I decided to create the initial table.  Nothing stops anyone from simply creating an array of 83 and just hard-coding the beautiful numbers into the array.  I mentioned that in the answer.

Comment: `constexpr std::array<int, N> generate_beautiful_numbers()` is an alternative.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Good evening. First of all sir, you provided a completely different approach to solve this. I was amazed at how easy it was to generate a beautiful number ( I guess I have to work on my logic skills a lot). Obviously it was a trade off between time and space but it works. One correction I would like to make is that ```return std::distance(values.begin(), iter) - 1;``` would give one less than the number(distance) we require as vectors start counting from 0. It was giving a different result. So by directly returning the distance between values.begin() & ter, the program worked.

Comment: @BeardedOwl -- Yes, I was a little torn on whether 1 should be subtracted.  But the general idea was that the answer was either going to be right on the nose of the binary search results, or one below.  So it almost came down to a matter of what the requirements are and possibly a sanity check after the `upper_bound` call.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things about the early set up.

1) From the input example you gave, it appears the t and each n need to be input sequentially, but your code prints the number of beautiful numbers before the next input is received.  I would suggest reading in t first, then looping through an array of size t to get all the inputs first.

2) The constraints aren't tested.  I would test the t and each value in the array mentioned before that the constraints are met, and either have the user try again if they aren't, or simply abort.

Comment: If I were to take the input in an array beforehand, I would require another loop to access the elements of the array and passing input one by one, so in this case, I thought I should do it simultaneously.